# Android Options Menu: Resource not found Exception: Only on 4.0.x

Tags: android, resources, contextmenu, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm not a beginner in Android development, but don't understand what I can do, to solve this problem.

These are the errors which will be thrown, when I open the option menu in my Activity.

It only throws some errors, if this is the **first** start of my Application.
If I start the App again, it will run without any errors. The context menu runs nicely and do what they have to do.

```
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712): **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1090046**
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1019)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:858)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:70)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$PanelFeatureState.getIconMenuView(PhoneWindow.java:3484)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.initializePanelContent(PhoneWindow.java:1124)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:579)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:845)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1637)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1964)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3546)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3519)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2603)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
03-06 10:24:10.285: E/AndroidRuntime(28712):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Many people said, you have to clean up the project or refresh the generated data,
but it still doesn't work.

I tried debugging my app on many devices, which have completely different Android versions.

For example, it works on an old device with 2.2 but not on my phone which has 4.0.3(Galaxy S2).

This is the java class:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate( R.menu.main_options_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

This is the xml for the Menu items:

```
      <menu xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:title="@string/menu_item_about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ueber"/>
     **<!--I don't list all the items!-->**
<!-- I'm sure, that all of the Resources are in the folders. The Strings are correct, the drawable, too.-->
         </menu>
```

Comment: After the clean - did you build it with Ctrl + B ? Can you find the resource reference somewhere in the generated java files?

Comment: I think you are importing android.R.java, try to import R.java instead

Comment: The #0x1090046 isn't in any gen file.

Comment: I work on a mac. What do you mean with build with Ctrl + B? I debug or run the app on my device. Normal case and what i do every time..

Comment: to which resource is this ID (0x1090046) pointing to in your R.java? is it main_options_menu?

Comment: It isn't the ID of the option menu. I import the correct R file...

Comment: Don't use smileys, and worlds like "Thanks" and signature. Please edit and remove.

Comment: need more info to resolve this, your log says it is not able to find 0x1090046, so want to know what it is pointing to? search for this ID in your R.java

Comment: I don't find the id in any R.java

Comment: I don't understand, why the application runs normal if i start the app again. At the second start, there are no errors. Nothing. It is really strange...

Comment: oh!... it might have got regenerated again.. Can u clean -> build -> run -> get the ID from exception -> search in R.java?

Comment: After clean up, i have the same ID: #0x1090046. Can't found it in the R.java again.

Comment: ok, so when is the exception thrown? is it when inflater.inflate( R.menu.main_options_menu, menu); is called?

Comment: No, the inflate runs correctly. It throws the Exception after it.

Comment: I solved the problem. It is a Version problem. If you say, the target Version is 4.1 or higher, you have to use the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html           There wasn't a problem with the generated files. The optionsMenu is in conflict with the titlebar in a lower Version of android. That's it.

Comment: Kindly Use this...
It's will be help for you....

[Show Icon and text properly][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716467/why-the-pictures-icon-dont-show-up-in-the-menu/15287560#15287560