# How to add icon on the android pop-up menu

Tags: android

I have tried a lot but i am not able to add icon on the pop-up menu.
First I create menu file i.e

```
<item
android:id="@+id/search"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
android:title="Search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom">

<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:title="Add"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:title="Edit"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

One button i added in layout/activity_main file

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onPopupButtonClick"/>
```

java file MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




}


public void onPopupButtonClick(View button) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, button);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, popup.getMenu());

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Clicked popup menu item " + item.getTitle(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    popup.show();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
   /* if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }*/

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In new Android version is deprecated. It's work correctly on Android 2.2.

> 1. Context menus: Do not support item shortcuts and item icons.
> 2. Options menus: The icon menus do not support item check marks and only show the item's condensed title. The expanded menus (only
>      available if six or more menu items are visible, reached via the
>      'More' item in the icon menu) do not show item icons, and item check
>      marks are discouraged.
> 3. Sub menus: Do not support item icons, or nested sub menus.

If you want add icon and show them in menu you have to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) or something similar.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716467/why-the-pictures-icon-dont-show-up-in-the-menu) you have more info about that.

Have fun.